# Tastypie & raw sql

Tags: django, tastypie

How do I get Tastypie to fetch a raw sql queryset? `queryset = Foo.objects.raw(sql)` does not seem to be working. Is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
class BarResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Bar.objects.all()

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        qs = Bar.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM foo_bar')
        return [row for row in qs]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
queryset = super(class_name, self).get_query_set()
return queryset.whatever()
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that but it is probably possible to create a manager and inject complex `WHERE` sql syntax using `extra()`. That should probably cover most use cases.

Comment: I've tried to override get_query_set() manager function and return queryset.raw() however it's throwing me an error;
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'raw'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override the dehydrate function to include raw sql syntax and or make a Per-Request Alterations To The Queryset http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html

I personally would much rather create a custom view function in view.py that matches whatever your api REST syntax is - for example /api/v1/rawsql  something like that to keep your patterns the same - you'd just be managing it differently.

Answer (score 0):

This works to me :D

```
class UsersResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        resource_name   = "users"
        queryset        = User.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']

   def obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        query = """
        SELECT 
            id, name
        FROM 
            users 
        ORDER BY name"""         
        qs = User.objects.raw(query)
        return [row for row in qs]
```