# tastypie :raw queries returning result with extra brackets

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm trying to use tastypie to get raw sql result. I have followed the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793785/tastypie-raw-sql). The idea is to put the raw sql in dehydrate function and return the queryset. But the result I got is like this:

```
{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 1}, "objects": [[["123", "name1"], ["124", "name2"]]]}
```

So I wonder how I can remove the extra square bracket in 'objects' and simply the result to look like this:

```
{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 1}, "objects": [["123", "name1"], ["124", "name2"]]}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Is this a blocking problem? Could you explain why?

Comment: Hi @DavidW. what do you mean by blocking problem? It just looks like an extra layer to me.